# Simplifiy and make an more efficient Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have been continually adding in complexity to my formulas to accomodate the large amount of data. I have been trying to simplify this excel formula but cannot seem to find a way that works well. I would appreciate any advice!

`` {=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(FullFlow_2,SMALL(IF(FullFlow_2[SN]=[@SN],ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN],1,1))+1),COLUMN(M$2)-COLUMN($L$2)),4)="Complete",INDEX(FullFlow_2,SMALL(IF(FullFlow_2[SN]=[@SN],ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN],1,1))+1),COLUMN(M$2)-COLUMN($L$2)),2),IF(VLOOKUP([@SN],FullSNList_2,8,FALSE)="None",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(M4),"`",""),TRIM($L4:L4),0)),INDEX(FullFlow_2,SMALL(IF(FullFlow_2[SN]=[@SN],ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN],1,1))+1),COLUMN(M$2)-COLUMN($L$2)),2)&"` ",INDEX(FullFlow_2,SMALL(IF(FullFlow_2[SN]=[@SN],ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN],1,1))+1),COLUMN(M$2)-COLUMN($L$2)),2)&" "),IF(OR(VLOOKUP([@SN],FullSNList_2,8,FALSE)="Dev",VLOOKUP([@SN],FullSNList_2,8,FALSE)="ECO",VLOOKUP([@SN],FullSNList_2,8,FALSE)="Rework"),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(M4),"`",""),TRIM($L4:L4),0)),INDEX(FullFlow_2,SMALL(IF(FullFlow_2[SN]=[@SN],ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN],1,1))+1),COLUMN(M$2)-COLUMN($L$2)),2)&"`  ",INDEX(FullFlow_2,SMALL(IF(FullFlow_2[SN]=[@SN],ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN],1,1))+1),COLUMN(M$2)-COLUMN($L$2)),2)&"  "),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(M4),"`",""),TRIM($L4:L4),0)),INDEX(FullFlow_2,SMALL(IF(FullFlow_2[SN]=[@SN],ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN],1,1))+1),COLUMN(M$2)-COLUMN($L$2)),2)&"`   ",INDEX(FullFlow_2,SMALL(IF(FullFlow_2[SN]=[@SN],ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN],1,1))+1),COLUMN(M$2)-COLUMN($L$2)),2)&"   ")))),"_")} ``

A little more info on the code. It is meant to scan a table and search for a step name (DOC###). Depending on other criteria's (if one column has none, rework, or broke, in it) spaces are added to the end to differentiate between them while being able to still be counted at a later step. Also, if a step is being done for the 2nd time, a period will be added afterwards.

I have been putting the formula in http://excelformulabeautifier.com/ to help read it a bit easier!

UPDATE: I have Modified the formula a bit and added explanations. The new code has replaced the old one in the body. I have attached pictures to show my explanation.

[Formula Explanation PG 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66kjI.png)

[Formula Explanation PG 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zvf5.png)

[Example Data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omzyD.png)

NOTES: In order for this to work for me, due to the circular references, I turned on Iterative Calculations and set the Max iterations to 2.

Comment: I can't believe this is man-written code! It is crazy :) - I suggest you start by figuring out what it does, then re-write it form scratch, even using VBA.

Comment: Note sure you have mentioned why you want to change the formula. Of course, it is not easy to maintain. Also, make the formula easier to read by noticing that certain expressions are heavily repeated, for reading purpose do a substitute for expressions such as: ROW(INDEX(FullFlow_2[SN] with maybe XX, then for ROW(FullFlow_2[SN])-XX,1,1))+1) with maybe YY, etc. Next step is to indent the IF statement. Then try to understand it.

Comment: And if you figured out what it is supposed to do, you can enrich your question by making a sample with sample data and expected output. A simplified example will yield usable answers for sure.

Comment: @NoChance regarding being man made. I have had a few formulas in that size. Usually they are created by helper columns and then you bunch it all up in to one by removing the say C2  and making it the formula you have in C2 and so on.

Comment: I would keep the "helper columns": they will make trouble-shooting much easier if you have an error. "Real-estate" in Excel is plentiful, and you can always Hide the columns or rows to keep them out of the way. Also if you leave this sheet, and come back to it in 6 months, will you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: I'm not even going to try.  I would suggest you write down an algorithm pr draw a flow diagram and recreate in Excel using simple formulas with one step per cell.

Comment: That's a lot to dig into, but a quick glance shows you're using VLOOKUP x4, which smart people tell me is slow and hard to use.  Any reason not to replace those VLOOKUPs with INDEX/MATCH?  Likewise, any reason not to name the ranges referenced in your COLUMN functions?  That won't shorten the formula, but it should make it easier to read and debug.

Comment: No reason for the Vlookups. I can change those! As far as the non-named region, That is scanning all previous columns in its row to determine if the output has been done before so it can add the "`" afterwords. (Circular reference, I know that is a no-no for speed but I couldn't find a better way)

Comment: With a beast of a formula like this, it might be better to use a VBA UDF. Is that an option for you?

Comment: I know of those but never used them before. I could attempt to learn that though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the VLookups from the formula made the calculation time a lot shorter! Thank you all for your ideas! Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated!